# Extracting package list from emacs

Tags: emacs

I would like to add emacs package list to my backuping script, so I need to somehow extract list of installed packages -- e.g., using the variable `package-activated-list` -- from command line. Is that even possible? I mean calling emacs with some sort of parameter so the output is the list of installed packages I can redirect into some file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe you want something like this:

```
emacs -batch -l ~/.emacs --eval='(message (mapconcat '"'"'symbol-name package-activated-list "\n"))'
```

See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BatchMode for how to run Emacs commands from the command line.

Comment: Your Lisp looks like it has a syntax error.  Anyway, you don't really need to `message` or `symbol-name` anything -- just `--eval="(mapcar 'print package-activated-list)"` would seem sufficient.  You also want to discard standard error, which contains various progress messages from Emacs.

Comment: Yeah, that works as well. So I believe the most convenient solution is `emacs -batch -l ~/.emacs --eval="(mapcar 'print package-activated-list)" 2>/dev/null`.

My earlier solution *looks* like it has a syntax error because of how you escape quotes in bash. But it does run correctly.

Comment: Oh, my bad, you're right; I failed to parse the quoting correctly. Using `message` has the distinct  disadvantage that the progress messages and the output will be mixed, whereas with `print` you have them separated.